# A set under multiplication by non-negative real numbers in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $S$ a closed subset of $X$. Is the set $\tilde S=\{rs;\ s\in S,\ r\geq 0\}$ also closed?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Take $S=(x=1)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, for example

Comment: Your definition of $S$ is not clear !

Comment: $S$ is the set of points with first coordinate $1$. Since $\frac 1 n (1,n) \to (0,1)$ it is clear that this is valid a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

This already fails for $X = \mathbb R^2$:
$$S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x,y \ge 0 \text{ and } x \, y = 1\}.$$

However, the result is true if $S$ is assumed to be compact.